# Linux Kernel how to import LIST_HEAD_INIT

Tags: c, linux, include, kernel

I am using the source code from `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git` .

The absolute path of my file is `/home/user/repos/linux/drivers/infiniband/hw/irdma/test_pble.c` .

The file contains the following code.

```
#include "pble.c"
#include "list.h"

int main(void) {
    struct irdma_pble_prm first = {
        .clist = LIST_HEAD_INIT{first.clist};
}
```

LIST_HEAD_INIT is declared in `/home/user/repos/linux/include/linux/list.h` .
My IDE CLion gives me the following warning: Use of undeclared identifier 'LIST_HEAD_INIT'.
How can I correctly import the macro LIST_HEAD_INIT?

Comment: paths to header directories are usually specified in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "linux/list.h"` if they are stored in the directory with your project. Although, you probably want to include the directory the linux headers are in as a system header with `-isystem /path/to/include/` compiler flag (or in your IDE) so you can do `#include <linux/list.h>`